# Recaptcha doesn't show up in django-crispy-forms form

Tags: python, django, recaptcha

I am trying to implement recaptcha in my django-crispy-forms form using [this repo](https://github.com/kbytesys/django-recaptcha2), however whenever I put it in my forms layout it doesn't show. Is there something I'm missing?

```
class ServerBumpFormView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
model = Server
template_name = "servers/server_bump_form.html"
success_url = reverse_lazy("servers:manage")
fields = ()

def get_queryset(self):
    if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
        return self.model.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
    return self.model.objects.all()

def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    form = super().get_form(form_class)
    form.helper = FormHelper()
    captcha = ReCaptchaField(widget=ReCaptchaWidget())
    form.helper.layout = Layout(
        'captcha',
    )
    form.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Bump', css_class='btn-blurple'))
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.bumpPoints = obj.bumpPoints + 1
        obj.last_bumped_at = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
        obj.save()

    return form
```

It also produces a KeyError

```
KeyError: "Key 'captcha' not found in 'ServerForm'. Choices are: ."
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also faced with the same issue and be able to solve it using HTML layout.

You can add ReCapcha html code using with HTML layout element.

```
form.helper.layout = Layout(
    HTML('<div class="form-group"><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="%s"></div></div>' %RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY),
)
```

Don't forget import HTML and your captcha code variable from settings or add it manually.

Comment: The user can still submit without doing the verification check, even though the recaptcha is present on screen.